# Forge 1.19.2 How to add layer to the player's model?

Tags: java, render, minecraft-forge

I want to render a default elytra model as a layer on the player, instead of manually positioning it like I did in here:

```
    public static void renderElytra(LivingEntity entity, float partialTicks, PoseStack poseStack, MultiBufferSource buffer, int packedLight) {
        if (getPlayerWings()) {
            Minecraft minecraft = Minecraft.getInstance();
            ElytraModel<LivingEntity> elytraModel = (ElytraModel<LivingEntity>) getElytraModel();

            minecraft.getTextureManager().bindForSetup(ELYTRA_TEXTURE);

            poseStack.pushPose();

            double bodyRotRadians = (double) Math.toRadians(entity.yBodyRot);

            // Calculate the offset positions based on the player's rotation
            // Adjust these values as needed to position the Elytra correctly on the player's back
            double xOffset = 0.1 * Math.sin(bodyRotRadians);
            double zOffset = -0.1 * Math.cos(bodyRotRadians);
            double xFlyOffset = -3 * Math.sin(bodyRotRadians);
            double zFlyOffset = 3 * Math.cos(bodyRotRadians);
            boolean isFlying = entity.isFallFlying();
            if (isFlying) {
                poseStack.translate(xFlyOffset, -0.4, zFlyOffset);
                poseStack.mulPose(Vector3f.YP.rotationDegrees(180F - entity.yBodyRot));
                poseStack.mulPose(Vector3f.ZP.rotationDegrees(180F));
                poseStack.mulPose(Vector3f.XP.rotationDegrees(90F - entity.getXRot()));
            } else {
                poseStack.translate(xOffset, 2.9, zOffset);
                poseStack.mulPose(Vector3f.YP.rotationDegrees(180F - entity.yBodyRot));
                poseStack.mulPose(Vector3f.ZP.rotationDegrees(180F));
            }
            float scale = 1.93F; // Adjust if needed
            poseStack.scale(scale, scale, scale);



            elytraModel.setupAnim(entity, 0, 0, partialTicks, 0, 0);

            elytraModel.renderToBuffer(poseStack, buffer.getBuffer(RenderType.entityCutoutNoCull(ELYTRA_TEXTURE)), packedLight, OverlayTexture.NO_OVERLAY, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);

            poseStack.popPose();
        }
    }
```

```
@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(value = Dist.CLIENT)
public class PlayerRendererHandler {

    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void onPlayerRender(RenderPlayerEvent.Post event) {
        if (ClientWingsData.getPlayerWings()) {
            ClientWingsData.renderElytra(event.getEntity(), event.getPartialTick(), event.getPoseStack(), event.getMultiBufferSource(), event.getPackedLight());
        }
    }
}
```

I managed to create an elytra layer:

```
@Mod.EventBusSubscriber(modid = EnderiteMod.MOD_ID, value = Dist.CLIENT)
public final class LayerRenderSubscriber {

    @SubscribeEvent(priority = EventPriority.LOW)
    public static void renderPlayer(final EntityRenderersEvent.AddLayers event) {
        LivingEntityRenderer<Player, PlayerModel<Player>> renderer = event.getRenderer(EntityType.PLAYER);
        ElytraLayer<Player, PlayerModel<Player>> layer = new ElytraLayer<>(renderer, event.getEntityModels());
        renderer.addLayer(layer);
    }
```

The problem is that I did not manage to actually implement the layer and add it to the player model, I do not know how to replace the player model or how to add an extra layer to it. I tried a lot of methods but none of them added the model. the closest I got was the PlayerModel.createMesh method but I couldn't manage to get it working. I also found the .render method but couldn't figure it out either.